# How to do a scanline fill with a self intersecting polygon?

Tags: vector-graphics, polygon, bezier-curve, drawing, scanline

I have a bezier curve and would like to draw it's stroke. To do that, I planned to approximate the stroke to a polygon and fill it with a scanline algorithm. While I feel confident about implementing the conversion and the scanline algorithm, I am unsure how to handle the situation when a polygon intersects itself.

If I don't treat it specially, it will look like on this picture on the left side, but what I am actually looking for is something like on the right side. Is there a popular method how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Read about winding order. The left one is usually called even odd winding rule.vand the other is just any number other than 0. What you do is you calculate how many points on the scanline then add a number if curve is intersecting upwards and subtract when down (or vice versa)